# Code does not run multiprocessing functions in python 3.8

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import time
import multiprocessing
start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print("Sleeping 1 second...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done Sleeping...")

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target= do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target= do_something)

p1.start()#these should run the procesess above but do nothing
p2.start()

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

This should print "Sleeping 1 second..." followed by "Done Sleeping..." but the code completely ignores p1.start() and just prints the last lines which show the time taken to run the code

All I get in the end is

```
Finished in 0.03 second(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

literally copied and pasted your code, it run as what you expected. to print "sleeping 1 sec" followed by "done sleeping".

```
Finished in 0.0 second(s)
Sleeping 1 second...
Sleeping 1 second...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
```

I know that youre following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso

it is a good one indeed, but you also need to listen to his explanation. he is really good at it.

he also explain how to turn to this output:

```
Sleeping 1 second...
Sleeping 1 second...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Finished in 1.01 second(s)
```

*note that the 'finished' is on the last row

Comment: I literally copied his code word by word but it didn't work, I also listened to his video and copy pasted some similar code from other forums that were working for other people but do not print anything for me. 
I'm left wondering if it has to do with my version of python or something else. I'm currently running ver 3.8.